# Using $predicted values of a randomForest object as predictor in training for another randomForest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, feature-engineering

I'm wondering if there is any problem in using the predicted values (based on OOB observations) of a randomForest object as a predictor in the prediction of another variable. Something like this using R:

```
rf_interim <- randomForest(z ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
z_pred <- rf_interim$predicted
rf <- randomForest(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + z_pred)
rf$predicted
```

Ulitmately on new data, I want to predict `z` in a first random Forest and use that prediction to predict `y` in a second random Forest. Will it for example skew the error prediction or mess with any of the other outputs? Does this approach make sense when `z` is a strong predictor for `y` but not initially observable?

Comment: is there any motivation for this?

Comment: So basically you have access to `x1, x2, x3` on Monday, but you don't have access to `z` until Tuesday and you can't wait until Tuesday to predict `y`?

Comment: @Sycorax Yes exactly. `z` and `y` are only observable later, not when I'm actually using the model to predict.

Comment: @utobi `z` is a strong predictor for `y`, which I ultimately want to predict. `x1`, `x2` and `x3` do well in predicting `z` not so much in predicting `y`.

Comment: (+1 fun question - and welcom to CV.SE). Yeah, that is probably not harmful but given what we want to do is $y=f^Y_{\text{t=2}}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ but we ultimately have to use $f^Y_{\text{t=1}}(x_1,x_2,x_3,f^{x_4}_{\text{t=1}}(x_1,x_2,x_3))$, we should first use $y=f^{Y}_{\text{t=1}}(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ as a relevant baseline. Short of doing that first we somehow "hope" that the error in the prediction of $\hat{x}_4$  is not too detrimental. Similarly, we probably need to train our $f^Y_{\text{t=2}}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ on *purposely noisy* $x_4$ otherwise we will face covariate shift when we validate.

Comment: Hi @usεr11852, thanks for the answer. With "using as baseline" you mean train both models and make sure that performance doesn't get worse with the "predicted predictor"?

Comment: I mean that a model $f_{t=1}^Y (x_1, x_2,x_3)$ should be trained and evaluated first as it is simpler to explain, deploy and test and then try to see if the chained approach gives an improvement. In my experience, often chaining multiple different models instead of having one well-tuned model gives marginal differences at the expense of a much more complicated modelling pipeline.

Comment: @usεr11852 regarding the second part of your answer, I mean to train and assess with the predicted x4 to begin with, not the real x4. So t=2 does not interest me, only the t=1 performance of the combined model. In my mind there maybe could be problems regarding the fact, that different OOB's are used for fY(x1,x2,x3,fx4) and fx4(x1,x2,x3), so maybe we somehow "leak" information we dont yet know?

Comment: Yeah, leakage is an issue, that's why I suggest you start with something not containing `x4` at all, to that effect $f^{x_4}_{t=1}(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ should be learned using a sample different from the one used for testing $f^{Y}_{t=1}(x_1,x_2,x_3,\hat{x}_4)$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first observed issue with this approach: since leakage is probably an issue when using OOB's twice, we need to assess performance on a test set instead on OOB's. Something like this:

```
rf_interim <- randomForest(z ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=train)
z_pred <- rf_interim$predicted
rf <- randomForest(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + z_pred, data=train)
predictions <- predict(rf, test)
mse <- sum((predictions - test$y)^2) / length(predictions)
```

So we don't use the `rf$mse` (uses OOB's) to assess performance but the MSE of the test set.